# Disable screen while current process still run

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a multiple record and image generation button. and each record take around 1 min to be generated one button submit. for example:

1. cat playing guitar with his friends  - [submit]
2. Dog catch squirrel on tree           - [submit]
3. A school of dolphin play ice hockey  - [submit]

The scenario is let said I submit no.1,  I want to disable all button from submitting while the process still runs, and enable again after the process done.

The reason is I want to prevent user from clicking multiple time and multiple process.
I expecting the all the button to disable after no.1 button submitted. and after the process completed, all button enable again.

Comment: disable the buttons once a request is made, enable them when a response is received

Comment: If you are using plain laravel(blade) plus javascript(jquery) then use ajax or axios for this (not plain form) Bind an on submit then disable the buttons like @JaromandaX said. If you are using frontend frameworks like react or vue, then use reactive variables to disable buttons.

Answer (score 0):

ok you problem use javascript dom html button onclik ="b1()"
and run your code

```
let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
let btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
let btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

function b1(){
  btn1.disabled = true
  btn2.disabled = true
  btn3.disabled = true
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).